# React does not re-render child component on setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am really new to react and hence to not quite understand all of the concepts, but as far as i understand, setState() should re-render all affected components. After googling around and trying for an hour i can't find something to make my code work:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fighting: false,
            health: 100,
            gold: 0,
            msgs: ["","","",""],
            feed: ["","","",""]
        };
        var intervalFighting;
        this.newFeed = this.newFeed.bind(this);
        this.newMsg = this.newMsg.bind(this);
        this.fighting = this.fighting.bind(this);
        this.fightToggle = this.fightToggle.bind(this);
        this.healingButton = this.healingButton.bind(this);
    }

    newFeed(newFeed) {
        let tempFeed = [this.state.feed[1],this.state.feed[2],this.state.feed[3]];
        this.setState({feed: [tempFeed[0],tempFeed[1],tempFeed[2],newFeed]});
    }

    newMsg(newMsg) {
        let tempMsgs = [this.state.msgs[1],this.state.msgs[2],this.state.msgs[3]];
        this.setState({msgs: [tempMsgs[0],tempMsgs[1],tempMsgs[2],newMsg]});
    }

    fightToggle() {
        if(this.state.fighting) {
            this.setState({fighting: false});
            if(this.intervalFighting != null) clearInterval(this.intervalFighting);
        }
        else {
            this.setState({fighting: true});
            this.intervalFighting = setInterval(this.fighting, 1000);
        }
    }

    fighting() {
        if(this.state.health == 0) {
            clearInterval(this.intervalFighting);
            this.setState({fighting: false})
        }
        if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
            console.log("Fighting")
            this.setState({health: this.state.health-1})
            if(Math.random() < 0.5) this.setState({money: this.state.money+1})
            if(Math.random() < 0.1) {
                this.newMsg("Wow, you just fought a boss and hence lost 10 health instead of the usual 1.");
                this.setState({gold: this.state.gold+20});
            }
        }
    }

    healingButton() {
        if(this.state.gold >= 10) {
            this.setState({health: 100, gold: this.state.gold-10})
            this.newFeed("You just healed yourself.")
        }
        else this.newFeed("You do not have enough money for this.")
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ItemShop gold = {this.state.gold} />
                <OwnHeader />
                <Fighting fighting = {this.state.fighting} health = {this.state.health} funcs = {[this.fightToggle, this.healingButton]}/>
                <Feed feed = {this.state.feed} />
                <Msg msg = {this.state.msgs} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The fighting component is just text and two buttons, for whom i give the appropriate onClick functions with funcs.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: how do you know something is not rerendering? what are you expecting to happen? are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Not a solution but just for your information, you should use the spread syntax  ```this.setState({feed: ...tempFeed, newFeed]});```
I also think there are issues with the way you pass your functions in your Fighting component but can't know for sure with what I see there.

Comment: I know that something is not rendering, because the <Fighting /> Component should update along with the fighting function, wich causes a text to change with the states of this.state.health and this.state.fighting, yet that does not happen

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer out, after a long session with google. It turns out, i needed to use componentWillReceiveProps() in order for this to work. [This link](https://medium.com/@admin_86118/react-re-render-child-components-on-parent-state-change-387720c3cff8) gives a nice explanation.
I am posting this answer in case anyone has the same problem and then hopefully this can help.